# How to debug uncannily accurate TensorFlow model?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm trying to create a model in line with the tutorial at https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/wide/, but I seem to be corrupting my data in some way, as I'm highly suspicious of the 97.9% accuracy on a very naive model.

I'm separating training and evaluation data with the following code, which seems reasonable to me:

```
  total_results = len(results)
  # Withhold some results from training for evaluation.
  withhold_index = total_results * 9 / 10
  training_df = get_data_frame_from_results(results[:withhold_index])
  eval_df = get_data_frame_from_results(results[withhold_index:])
```

However, this is giving me numbers which seem way too high:

```
accuracy: 0.979
accuracy/baseline_label_mean: 0.021
accuracy/threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.979
auc: 0.443042
global_step: 200
labels/actual_label_mean: 0.021
labels/prediction_mean: 0.0288264
loss: 0.288538
precision/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.0
recall/positive_threshold_0.500000_mean: 0.0
```

The model creation/evaluation happens here:

```
  def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(training_df)

  def eval_input_fn():
    return input_fn(eval_df)

  m = tf.contrib.learn.LinearClassifier(
      feature_columns=[...],
      model_dir=model_dir)
  m.fit(input_fn=train_input_fn, steps=200)
  eval_results = m.evaluate(input_fn=eval_input_fn, steps=1)
```

I suspect there's a simple error here, but I'm not seeing it.

Comment: What does your data look like? If one class takes up 97.9% of the data, you get to 97.9% accuracy by just always predicting the majority label.

Comment: Ah, yes, that's almost certainly what's happening.  The data is heavily skewed in one direction, so I'll need to adjust for this.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You are working with a unbalanced dataset in which the number of examples in one class is significantly higher than the other. For this unbalanced problem, a random predictor can easily achieve a high accuracy by predicting the label of the majority class for all testing data.

To correctly validate the performance of this model, you can look at the auc. Here the auc you achieved is only 0.44, which is very poor. A better metric to validate the performance of problem with unbalanced dataset is auc_precision_recall. I suspect the auc_precision_recall for this problem will be fairly small (e.g. 0.02) if you print it out.

You can read through this post to have a better understanding of auc:
https://classeval.wordpress.com/simulation-analysis/roc-and-precision-recall-with-imbalanced-datasets/

Answer (score 0):

This depends on your model and your data. You can get 100% accuracy on the training set by overfitting, and [people](http://cs.nyu.edu/~wanli/dropc/) have gotten <1% error rate on the test set of MNIST.